# Tensorflow backprop through rnn ValueError

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am using a recurrent neural network in tensorflow with BasicLSTMCells. Basically, I have an input sequence of word ids, I convert each id to word embeddings, pass the word embeddings one at a time through the rnn, and then make a prediction for a single word after reading the whole sequence. My embedding matrix is of dimension V x H where V is the size of my vocabulary and H is the number of hidden units in my rnn. In order to make a prediction for the next word, I multiply my hidden vector by a weight matrix of size H x V and then compute a softmax. With the setup I described, everything seems to work as expected. I'm able to train on some examples and make reasonable predictions.
However, I've noticed that if I try to use the transpose of the embedding matrix, which will be a matrix of size H x V, instead of a separate matrix for the softmax layer, tensorflow raises a value error claiming that the dimensions of something it's not specifying don't have the same rank. I've verified that the dimensions of my embedding matrix (well, its transpose) are the same as those of the separate softmax matrix I'm creating. Changing just the one line of code from using my embedding matrix vs a separate softmax weight matrix causes the error.
I created a relatively small program to demonstrate what I'm trying to do and to show what causes the error. I was not able to make the error occur on a smaller network when I tried with just a single hidden layer network.

```
import sys
import time
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.models.rnn import rnn
from tensorflow.models.rnn import rnn_cell
from tensorflow.models.rnn.rnn_cell import BasicLSTMCell
import numpy as np

INPUT_LENGTH = 17
BATCH_SIZE = 20
VOCAB_SIZE = 11
NUM_EPOCHS = 1000
HIDDEN_UNITS = 100

class Model(object):
    def __init__(self, is_training):
        initializer = tf.random_uniform_initializer(-1.0, 1.0)

        self._target = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [BATCH_SIZE, VOCAB_SIZE])
        self._input_data=tf.placeholder(tf.int32,[BATCH_SIZE, INPUT_LENGTH])

        self.embedding = tf.get_variable("embedding",
                                    [VOCAB_SIZE, HIDDEN_UNITS],
                                    initializer=initializer)

        self.inputs = tf.split(1, INPUT_LENGTH,
                          tf.nn.embedding_lookup(self.embedding, self._input_data))

        self.inputs2 = [tf.squeeze(input_, [1]) for input_ in self.inputs]

        cell = rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=HIDDEN_UNITS)

        initial_state = cell.zero_state(BATCH_SIZE, tf.float32)
        outputs, states = rnn.rnn(cell, self.inputs2,
                                  initial_state=initial_state)

        self._outputs = outputs[-1]

        self.soft_w = tf.get_variable("softmax_w",
                                 [HIDDEN_UNITS, VOCAB_SIZE],
                                 initializer=initializer)


        prod = tf.matmul(self._outputs, self.soft_w)
#uncommenting out the following line causes the error
#        prod = tf.matmul(self._outputs, self.embedding, False, True)
        soft_b = tf.get_variable("softmax_b", [VOCAB_SIZE],
                                 initializer=initializer)
        self._logits = tf.nn.bias_add(prod,soft_b)
        self._loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(self._logits,
                                                             self._target)

        if not is_training:
            return

        learning_rate = .010001
        optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
        self._train_op = optimizer.minimize(self._loss)

    def train(self, sess, inputs, targets):
        t = np.zeros((BATCH_SIZE, VOCAB_SIZE))
        for i, target in enumerate(targets):
            t[i,target] = 1.0

        inputs = np.array(inputs)
        inputs = inputs.reshape(BATCH_SIZE,INPUT_LENGTH)

        fd = {self._target:t,
              self._input_data:inputs}
        o = sess.run([self._train_op, self._loss, self._outputs, self.embedding, self.soft_w], feed_dict = fd)
        print o[2].shape
        print o[3].shape
        print o[4].shape
        sys.exit()
        return np.mean(o[1])

#this just generates dummy data
def read_data_rows(count):
    ret = []
    for i in range(count):
        inputs = [4] * INPUT_LENGTH
        output = 1
        ret.append((inputs, output))
    return ret


def main():
    start = time.time()
    tf.set_random_seed(1)

    print "creating model",time.time()-start
    m = Model(is_training=True)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        print "initializing variables", time.time()-start
        tf.initialize_all_variables().run()

        for epoch in range(NUM_EPOCHS):
            train_rows = read_data_rows(100)
            for row_num in range(0, len(train_rows), BATCH_SIZE):
                qs = []
                ans = []
                batch = train_rows[row_num:row_num+BATCH_SIZE]
                for b in batch:
                    qs.append(b[0])
                    ans.append(b[1])
                m.train(sess, qs, ans)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The error I see is ValueError: Shapes TensorShape([Dimension(100)]) and TensorShape([Dimension(17), Dimension(100)]) must have the same rank
when uncommenting the line I mentioned above. What is the cause of the error I'm seeing? Why is the embedding matrix not treated the same way as the matrix self.soft_w?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 0.6.0 (and earlier) release of TensorFlow had a bug in the implementation of gradients for `tf.nn.embedding_lookup()` and `tf.gather()` when the indices argument (`self._input_data` in your code) had more than one dimension.

Upgrading to the latest source release should fix this error. Otherwise, [this commit](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/f2eae4b3d27a4dc6d1f591f55a50fb3e1984a287) has the relevant change (to `array_grad.py`) that will enable your program to work.